# How to create a dataframe with only certain columns from a csv in R

Tags: r, csv, dataframe

I imported my csv file like this.

```
my.xldataset <- read.csv('http://www.math.smith.edu/sasr/datasets/help.csv')
```

Now I'm looking to create a dataframe with only these columns from the csv file (id, pcs1, mcs1, substance, and race group). I know it's a data.frame function but I'm a little confused on how to get the csv file to display only these select columns. How do I go about doing this? I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can subset the data.frame `my.xldataset`:

```
df <- my.xldataset[,c("id","pcs1",  "mcs1", "substance", "racegrp")]
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `fread` from `data.table` package

```
# Fast and convenient
library(data.table)
fread('http://www.math.smith.edu/sasr/datasets/help.csv', select=c('id', 'pcs1', 'mcs1', 'substance','racegrp'))
```

Or you could use `sqldf` # this is probably the easiest if data set is large.

```
# Read csv
my_xldataset <- read.csv('http://www.math.smith.edu/sasr/datasets/help.csv')
#Gsub "." with "_" because of sqldf
colnames(my_xldataset) <- gsub("\\.","_",colnames(my_xldataset))

library(sqldf)
my.xldataset <- sqldf("select id, pcs1, mcs1, substance, racegrp from my_xldataset")
# Show output
head(my.xldataset)

  id     pcs1     mcs1 substance racegrp
1  1 54.22583 52.23480   cocaine   black
2  2 59.56066 41.72696   alcohol   white
3  3 58.45777 56.77131    heroin   black
4  4 46.60988 14.65925    heroin   white
5  5 31.41642 40.67421   cocaine   black
6  6 43.20495 50.05917   cocaine   black
```

Comment: This is great too. Thank you very much